# How to propose new tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, tag-wikis

When I was adding a tag to my question, I looked it up and found it doesn't have a wiki summary and navigated to a page that says:

Tag wikis help introduce newcomers to the tag. They contain an overview of the topic defined by the tag, along with guidelines on its usage.

All registered users may propose new tag wikis.

(Note that if you have less than 20000 reputation, your tag wiki will be peer reviewed before it is published.)

How can I propose new tag wikis?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a "create tag wiki" button right on that page.

Comment: I added an image for the screen

Comment: @Akram: yep. Right under that text is where there's a button on my screen. On a site where I have less reputation, it reads "Propose Tag Wiki". It only does not appear if I am not logged in.